# List all accessible ports from private network

Tags: nmap

I am connected to internet via the wifi provided by an Airport.
I can't connect via SSH to my server. So, Airport may block port 22.

Is there a way to use nmap to list all ports I can access through the wifi ?

Comment: "Yes". Did you read `man nmap` to find out how to get it to list the port(s) you want to scan?

Comment: Yes I did, but didn't found my answer there

Answer (score 1):

You can list all open ports on a given host or on hosts in a range using nmap.

However, nmap can't tell you which ports are blocked by the airport wifi in general. You might try a port scan against a non-existent but routable host and see whether the wifi gateway rejects some connection attempts, which should look different from unanswered connection attempts.

Comment: Like a verbose mode for nmap telling me at which point the connection is rejected ?

Comment: No, nmap shows the state of ports (open, closed, filtered, unfiltered) but does not show where in the route this happens. A tool like tcptraceroute might be able to do that for single port numbers.

Comment: A Linux system may even have a version of `traceroute` that can do exactly that when the proper options are used: `traceroute -T -p 22 my-ssh-server.example`